# How to pass values from SP to SP?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a question, I have a Stored Procedure which returns a value. This Stored Procedure is being executed within another SP and I need to transfer the value into this SP. How can I accomplish this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Example:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[isp_CREATE_CONFIG]

@CFG_KEY VARCHAR(15)
, @CFG_SHORTVALUE INT
, @CFG_LONGVALUE VARCHAR(200)
, @CFG_DESC VARCHAR(250)
, @CFG_SHORT_DESC VARCHAR(100)
, @CFG_MISC1 VARCHAR(50)
, @CFG_MISC2 VARCHAR(50)
, @CFG_MISC3 VARCHAR(50)
, @CFG_MISC4 VARCHAR(50)
, @CFG_MISC5 VARCHAR(50)
, @CFG_USER VARCHAR(20)
, @CFG_MSG VARCHAR(250) OUTPUT

AS

DECLARE 
@c_ErrMsg VARCHAR(200)
, @c_ErrNum VARCHAR(5)
, @c_Continue INT
, @c_Date VARCHAR(20)


/* Assign value to local variables */
SET @c_Date = GETDATE()
SET @c_Continue = 0

/* Run Validations */
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CONFIG(NOLOCK) WHERE cfg_key = @CFG_KEY)
    BEGIN
        SET @c_ErrNum = 60001
        SET @c_ErrMsg = 'Configuration Key (' + @CFG_KEY + ') already exist. Please check System Configuration. Error: ' + @c_ErrNum
        SET @CFG_MSG = @c_ErrMsg
        SET @c_Continue = 1
    END



/* Create Configuration */
SET @CFG_MSG = ''

IF @c_Continue = 0
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CONFIG(NOLOCK) WHERE cfg_key = @CFG_KEY)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO CONFIG
                    (
                        cfg_key         , cfg_short_value   , cfg_long_value    , cfg_desc          ,cfg_short_desc
                        , cfg_misc1     , cfg_misc2         , cfg_misc3         , cfg_misc4
                        , cfg_misc5     , cfg_add_who       , cfg_edit_date     , cfg_edit_who
                    )
                VALUES
                    (
                        @CFG_KEY        , @CFG_SHORTVALUE   , @CFG_LONGVALUE    , @CFG_DESC         , @CFG_SHORT_DESC
                        , @CFG_MISC1    , @CFG_MISC2        , @CFG_MISC3        , @CFG_MISC4
                        , @CFG_MISC5    , @CFG_USER         , @c_Date           , @CFG_USER
                    )

                SET @CFG_MSG = 'Configuration has been created.'            
            END
    END     

GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored procedure that returns the value has a parameter declared as OUTPUT, something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_returning_proc (@ret VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN .... END
```

If you want to use this value you need to call the STORED PROCEDURE like this:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(10);
EXEC my_returning_proc @var OUTPUT;
PRINT @var
```

The key's here is to add OUTPUT into EXEC statement

EDIT: Thanks for providing example.
For your case you would call the stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @var_returned VARCHAR(250);
EXEC [dbo].[isp_CREATE_CONFIG] 'BLAH', 0, 'BLAH', 'BLAH', 'BLAH', ......, @var_returned OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the OUTPUT part.

Answer (score 1):

By return a value, I assume you mean using `return`.  You can also declare output parameters for the stored procedure.

Here is how:

```
declare @retval int;

exec @retval = <stored procedure call>
```

Here is a simple code sample anyone can try:

```
create procedure dum as return 5

declare @retval int;

exec @retval = dum

select @retval
```

I use this technique all the time to return status from stored procedures.

Comment: I do not believe stored procedure returns value like this

Comment: Hmmm. Why doesn't MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) say that procedures can return values?